# Popup from grid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, grid, popup

I have a Rad grid (telerik UI). one of my requirement is,if user clicks one of column (column contains imagebutton) another pop-up has to be open with grid and user has to enter values within inner grid. Pop-up needs to have three buttons like save, cancel and close. Any insight/help on how to proceed will be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at [Telerik Popup Edit Form documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/popup-edit-form)?

Comment: Also, here is a [demo from Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window) for window popup when editing RadGrid. Code included.

Comment: Thank you Gunnar... Let me look at both link